# How can I narrow a question about free will, qadr, and justice down enough to fit islam.se?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

My question [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37835/what-notions-of-free-will-and-qadr-exist-in-the-different-theological-sects) was closed for being too broad. The only way I can think of to narrow this down substantially would be to restrict it to a single school of aqidah and only use one of the three questions I put in boldface. I talked about this at length [with Medi1Saif in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35546311#35546311) (the conversation spans what you get by clicking the "next day" button twice), but that didn't really resolve the issue.

I think these questions point out an important problem in aqidah and would be a worthwhile addition to islam.se. How can I narrow the post down sufficiently to remain open? I'm happy making 9 questions for each combination of 3 schools of aqidah and each of the 3 boldfaced questions, if that's required. I can also frame the problem more concretely if necessary; while talking to Medi1Saif about the issues in chat, it turned out that the inconsistencies I (and many other Non-Muslims) see with these doctrines took some time to outline precisely enough for him to realize what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

The topic of "multiple-question questions" has been raised on meta.SE a number of times: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2995/351283) [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208859/351283) [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82520/351283) [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44297/351283) [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120633/351283) [6](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122361/351283).

> The goal of questions on Stack Overflow is to be clear, concise, and answerable. A multi-part question is none of these things. -- [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44301/351283) ♦, 2010

The problem is that they're not particularly compatible with how the site is designed (e.g. maybe a sub-question is a duplicate; perhaps an answerer has expertise only to answer one sub-question.)

The same thing comes up on math.SE occasionally, particularly where students ask for help with multiple homework questions in a single post.  In this context, this solution has worked:

> If you can't isolate that concept, ask about the questions in separate posts, but **space them out** - **if the questions are related, you might learn enough from the first question that you don't have to ask the others**, and in any case it's a little impolite to fill the questions page with only your questions.  -- [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2697/91818), 2011

So the algorithm is:

1. Ask a "clear, concise, and answerable" question.
2. Understand answer(s).
3. If there's more to understand, write another "clear, concise, and answerable" question that has been adapted according to the previous answers.

Comment: It's not so clear to me that the posts by Atwood and Yuan apply here; it's easy to ask about a short programming problem or math exercise in an isolated concise way without losing anyway, but with multifaceted issues like free will, predestination, and justice that form a context for each other, if you isolate them you lose something. The top answer to your [first reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2995/multi-question-questions-how-best-to-handle-them) even says "If the sub-questions (...) are closely related, then they should stay with the question."

Comment: That being said, I already suggested in my question that I would attempt breaking these closely related questions apart, but I'm already anticipating the frustration of "nope, still too broad, rinse and repeat", which is why I'm asking for specific advice.