# What can I do to improve this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Islam Stack Exchange post: [Al-Qadar and the ability to work hard](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/40903/al-qadar-and-the-ability-to-work-hard)

Salaam Aalykum.

I have not yet received a relevant response to this question. Is there anything I can do to further improve my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Sorry, I voted to close this without leaving a comment.  And kudos to you for asking here.)

The <s>question is</s> questions are:

> In the context of the aforementioned Hadith, what does my laziness with regards to my school work mean? Am I not disciplined when it comes to school work because I am destined to not work hard in school?

It's asking the community here to judge whether or not you personally are destined to be lazy, undisciplined, etc.  Who knows?  We can't realistically do more than guess; we're just random people on the Internet.

We strive for expert answers, not best guesses.

Such questions get closed because they're more about [counselling](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/868/17163) than Islam.

#### How to improve it?

I suggest editing to:

- **Write one question.**  It's amazingly easy for people to misunderstand questions, and moreso when there's [multiple questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions) around.  Strive to write a single, unambiguous question, and write the remainder of the post with one purpose: to help understand that single question, e.g. by giving context (why you ask; what you know; etc.).
- **Make the question about Islam.**  We're here to learn about Islam; this question is currently more about you than Islam.  (As a start, try phrasing the question without words like "my" and "I".)
- **Help the reader quickly identify the exact question.**  Answerers will want to read the question, and get straight to answering the question.  They don't want to read about your relationship with your parents, how good/bad a Muslim you are, etc.
- **Make the title the question** not just a bunch of keywords put into a sentence.  See [Advice for writing question titles on Islam.SE](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/advice-for-writing-question-titles-on-islam-se).  Someone reading the title will already know what to expect if they click the question.
- **Trim back the personal details.**  Make it read like an academic question, which is detached from your personal life.  It can be personally motivated, but the question should be about Islam.
- **Make the question relevant to others.**  From the [How to Ask](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page:

  > We like to help as many people at a time as we can. Make it clear how your question is relevant to more people than just you, and more of us will be interested in your question and willing to look into it.
- **Tighten the question.**  *What does [hadith] imply [my behavior] means?* is vague.

Comment: JazakAllahu khyran for your detailed response. I have edited my question according to the suggestions you have provided.