# Illicit behavior and abuse and censorship

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

In [Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/) community, I raised a [challenge](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-it-true-that-in-islam-men-enjoy-more-value-and-privilege-how-god-the-religi) (*due to the my first comment*) that illustrates the problems of the Islamic religion and needs to be clarified and examined in order to determine whether what I asked really represents the failures of this religion or not.

But moderators are limiting and censoring my question and preventing it being discussed and analyzing, and try to disappoint and disrupt me from this community.

Please consider my complaint.

The committee did not seem to be a professional environment on the Stack Exchange.

It seems that the community supports the questions that they are promoting and advocating, and that the questions that present the problems of Islamic religion are blocked and deprived.

Please check my problem and correct this community and suspend my questions if my claim is correct.

Comment: Please note that this challenge did not raised, because I want to be raise. But it raised because of contradiction, Distortions and beliefs problems in Islam religion that they create it's community and they have been representing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not an executive, but I am a [Stack Exchange Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do). One of my primary jobs is to make sure communities such as this one are well moderated. Since this site has not yet hosted a moderator election, it's my responsibility to appoint [diamond moderators](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). So I'm always on the lookout for times when the community is not running smoothly. One common point of contention is when it's appropriate to close a question.

So let's look at [your closed question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-god-of-islam-righteous-justice):

1. The first thing I notice is that it was closed by 5 users:

   [image: 5 close votes]

   Since closing a question typically requires [5 close votes](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions), the diamond moderator's vote acted like that of any other user. Often this is a purposeful behavior by a moderator to allow the community to decide to close the question and to avoid imposing their will. There aren't any reopen votes just yet, but the community could decide to open the question once all the problems have been fixed.
2. The question has been edited 13 times so far. The most recent changes the title from:

   > Is God of Islam Righteous? Is it true that in Islam, men enjoy more value and privilege?

   to:

   > Is God of Islam Righteous/ justice?

   That indicates to me that you haven't quite settled on the question you are attempting to ask. Good, answerable questions tend to be focused on just one point rather than the extremely general question the second title suggests.
3. I'm not an expert on Islam, but I have seen similar [questions about Christianity](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/). Asking about how traditional gender roles are just or work in a modern context requires a good deal of care. You made a valiant effort, but I think your question falls short. And it seems 5 users of the site agree.
4. Questions suggesting problems with Islam *can* be asked without being closed (see: [Does Islam teach subjugation and inequality of women, or is that due to a wrong interpretation of the religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38338/does-islam-teach-subjugation-and-inequality-of-women-or-is-that-due-to-a-wrong)). It requires a certain open-mindedness to ask. I think it would be productive to think more on [one of the comments](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-god-of-islam-righteous-justice#comment73847_43898) you got:

   > Too many questions ->too broad yeah basically same topic but the questions discuss distinct topics[.] [Why we should avoid asking multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions) [Besides] the partial questions 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8 have been addressed on the site and the claim of 7 is only partly true!—[Sassir](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/16877/sassir)

On the whole, I don't see any abuse or censorship here. This is just how the community functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Islam — Stack Exchange** is a site for getting expert answers to practical and *answerable* questions on the topic of Islam. We are not a typical Internet forum; rhetorical questions are not a thing we do here.

- If your goal in asking your question was to challenge the beliefs people hold, **ask it somewhere else**.
- If your goal in asking your question was to get people to examine the failures of their religion, **ask it somewhere else**.
- If your goal in asking your question was to bring up a topic to be discussed and analysed, **ask it somewhere else**.

However, if your goal is because you actually want an *expert answer* to something you don't know about the topic of Islam, then go ahead and ask it here. But if you care enough about getting that answer, it behooves you to write it well (hint: our help centre is full of [valuable information](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)) and work *with* the community so that the experts that you want to answer it actually take interest: **The more care you show towards your own question, the more likely experts will care enough to answer it.**

Writing a good question is hard, nobody's saying it's not. And nobody's saying that just because you put a lot of work into a question means it'll be accepted by the community; communities can be fickle beasts. But ranting and throwing around accusations instead of putting in the required effort really isn't a productive alternative.

Comment: You are lying. You acts fraudulently and abusively, contrary to the rules. [The question is discussed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/43898/is-god-of-islam-righteous-justice) was editing from firs to be more clear. You made my question on-hold and this is contrary to the law, because my question is practical answerable question. (I claim). But because of the logical problems in the religion you represent, my question is not the desire of people like you, and it contradicts your beliefs. The paradox that needs to be discussed, but you are discussing with blocking my question!

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be a way for senior executives and `Stack Exchange` builders to **monitor** who set up community in line with their alleged goals of the community and their activities.

But if this is the case, then we want to be aware of those users who are moderators of these communities, and we can make our own `feedback` on the internal work of the communities in the eyes of senior executives.