# Can we have a general type of answering any islam related question so that answer criteria is met easily

Tags: bug, answers

I will start with example.

Solomon threatened queen of Sheba with military action when she refused to accept Islam by peaceful message.

When did solomon do this?

What was the reason behind this?

What can be inferred by action of solomon?

I want to educate non muslims and muslims so that questions here and on other sites can be tackled with less pain.

Another example Saudi clerics like utheymeen say it's not correct to eat meat slaughtered by one who doesnt pray.

Is it applicable to lands of disbelievers, where most muslims don't pray?

Why did he say that?

Answer (score 3):

If you ask a question that requires an enormous answer, it's likely to go unanswered simply because it requires too much effort for a few Internet points.

There's a bunch of reasons to ask one (answerable) question at a time: see [Why we should avoid asking multi-question questions](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2965/why-we-should-avoid-asking-multi-question-questions).  It's now described as part of the "too broad" close reason:

> Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.** See the [How to Ask](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Upvote for effort